# Suggestion for plants in pot on window where there are lots of sunshines

Tags: flowers, containers

I am in New Zealand, even it is winter but in my place, the window has always been shined by the sunshine and it is really hot. I am wondering if there is any plant in a pot (having flower) that I can consider putting there for making my room more lively?

Comment: which direction does the window face?  south?

Comment: Hi, it is North East

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a perfect place for cacti. Cactus plants love sunshine all day, a north facing window in your country is ideal. They also give beautiful flowers in spring.

Comment: I think there is a variety of cactus plants, I am wondering which ones having the good-looking flower in general then ?

Comment: Good-looking is subjective. Most cacti have impressive flowers, different sizes, different colors. Maybe do some google image research first, to see what you like?